# Why are there two pronunciations for "either"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, old-english, historical-change

A few weeks ago, I had a conversation with an individual who told me that pronouncing the word "either" is wrong when pronounced like \ˈī-thər\ instead of \ˈē-thər\ , but I didn't argue the point because I'd done no research on it myself. So I looked the word up on Merriam Webster Online and wasn't at all surprised to find that both pronunciations are in fact legitimate.

Which brings me to my question: what is the history of this word? How was it pronounced in old English? Were both pronunciations common hundreds of years ago? I was unable to glean much from Merriam Webster Online apart from some small fact that the word is somehow related to *whether*.

EDIT:
I dug up some additional information about the origins or either, and I'm hoping that someone can shed some light upon what it means.

> O.E. ægðer,  contraction of æghwæðer  "each of two, both," from a  "always" + ge-  collective prefix + hwæðer  "which of two, whether."
>   Modern sense of "one or the other of two" is early 14c.

I took this directly from [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/either), but I have no idea what language those words come from.

Comment: Let's call the whole thing off.

Comment: More importantly, why are there three spellings for "there"?

Comment: I find myself alternating, especially when reading a book out loud.

Comment: @Alan - that would make a good question!

Comment: @Alan: there aren't. They're two different words, plus a contraction, that happen to be alike in their pronunciation.

Comment: @Steve: That was just my way of pointing out that "there" was misspelled in the original title. :)

Comment: So you can choose either one.

Comment: You can add neither to the list as well. I've heard it both ways as well.  I grew up saying it as /nī-thər/, fwiw.

Comment: What I heard (another "hearsay" answer, so I just make a comment) was that Prince Albert, being of German origin, used the pronunciation suggested by German, and then it subsequently became popular among the English.

Comment: @AlanHogue - Their, they're now, don't get over-excited.  You know its not good for your blood pressure.

Comment: @mmyers, I don't get the joke..?

Comment: @Pacerier [Just a little Gershwin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOILZ_D3aRg).

Comment: Made famous by Harry and Sally https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YxJ52T21jY

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've always been told and believed that \ˈī-thər\ (IPA /ˈaɪðər/) is the correct pronunciation, albeit both are indeed common nowadays. From what I am aware, etymologists and linguists believe this was the original pronunciation of the word too. Other contemporary Germanic languages (including the closest modern relatives, Dutch and German), suggest this pronunciation of the first syllable is correct — they have arguably been less altered/bastardised from [Old Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Germanic). [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_english) (Anglo-Saxon) we know to be an almost purely Germanic language, and thus by simple statistical analysis (as is often employed in historical linguistics) we can be quite confident that this was the historically correct pronunciation.

Comment: Hey, if it was good enough for Beowulf, it's good enough for everyone!

Comment: @Noldorin - you're a well of knowledge! This is exactly what I was looking for. I had a suspicion that \ˈī-thər\ was probably the original pronunciation, but I had nothing to ground it on.

Comment: @Jagd: Glad to help. I'm no linguist, but I've heard this on good authority and it seems to verify. :)

Comment: What about poor old Frisian or Scots as relatives as English?

Comment: @itrekkie: True, they are the closest. But Scots in particular is so similar to English and has evolved in tandem that it doesn't say much.

Comment: In German, 'ie' is vocalized as a long e and 'ei' is vocalized as a long i.  In English, 'ie' is typically vocalized as a long i (as in *pie*) so it seems reasonable that 'ei' should be vocalized as a long e.  I won't get into the Dutch pronunciation of 'ei' because Americans can't form that diphthong. ;-)

Comment: @oosterwal: That's not at all true. The simple "reversal" you propose has no basis in history I'm afraid. English and German share a common ancestor (in the early first millennium AD?) and this feature of pronunciation remains common to them/unchanged since. English pronunciation is of course much more variable, largely thanks to multiple sources. Note that `pie` is of Latin origin.

Comment: @Noldorin:  I sit corrected.  The 'ie' at the end of 'cookie' definitely makes a long e sound.

Comment: @oosterwal: Hah, yes. English is unfortunately not a very predicatlbe language phonetically, by any means...

Comment: @noldorin Which phonetic alphabet are you using? Depending on that, your transcription of “either” could be read as either /ˈaɪðər/ or /ˈiːðər/.

Comment: I am Italian. At school I was taught that /ˈaɪðər/ is British English and /ˈiːðər/ is American English. Since we were learning British English our teacher encouraged us to use /ˈaɪðər/. I am not sure if all this is correct.

Comment: @Jonathan, Giorgio: I'm afraid I don't understand IPA, but I think that /ˈaɪðər/ is correct for British English.

Comment: @Noldorin You *really* need to learn IPA. Not only is it the standard form, it’s **much, much easier** to use than these ridiculous see-it-and-spell-it systems, which never work at all. I was aghast to find people here using anything else.

Comment: @tchrist: The problem is, IPA is so useless in just about every other walk of life. I spend time here out of my own will to help, and I fear investing the time into learning IPA is significant and of little return. Especially when your average person doesn't understand it either. Nonetheless, if I *do* decide it's useful at some point, do you suggest any learning resources?

Comment: @Noldorin IPA, I confess is bothersome to memorise but it is r _useful_ when looking up a word and you want to know its pronunciation. I'd hazard a guess that all bilingual and the majority of monolingual dictionaries employ the same phonemic system.

Answer (score 14):

It's a rather difficult question. Both pronunciations are correct today—I think you'd be hard-pressed to find a dictionary that would disagree with that. So, the individual you encountered was wrong about "ī-thər" (I assume you mean the pronunciation that's like "EYE-ther") being wrong. But this question is about the history, and the word has been spelled (and presumably pronounced) in a variety of ways across the years. The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) lists the following forms ("OE" stands for "Old English," and "ME" stands for "Middle English"):

> OE ǽg-, œ́g-, éghwæðer, OE–ME ǽgðer, ME eigðer, (ME Orm.
>   eȝȝðer), ME æiðer, aieþer, ME eiðer, eiþer, ME aiþer, aither, ayther,
>   ( ayder, ME eyder), ME–15 ether, (? ME–15 aþer, ather, athir, ME
>   euther, ewther), ME–16 eyther, eythir, (ME eithar), 15 eather, ME–
>   either.

What's interesting is that some of these spellings seem to suggest that the modern pronunciation "should" be "AY-ther" (IPA /ˈeɪðər/), but this pronunciation seems to be recorded only as a dialectal variant. It's not considered standard.

I don't actually think we need to compare to German and Dutch, since so many earlier forms in English are attested, but in any case the cognate words are German *jeder* (IPA /ˈjeːdɐ/, roughly "YAY-duh"), and Dutch *ieder* (IPA /iːdər/, roughly "EE-der"). In fact, both of these would correspond to the English pronunciation "EE-ther" (IPA /ˈiːðər/) rather than "EYE-ther" (IPA /ˈaɪðər/). I think some people may be misled by their knowledge of the "ei" digraph used in modern German to represent /aɪ/, but in fact this is completely irrelevant with regard to the early Germanic etymology of the word, since the German word cognate to *either* is not spelled with "ei."

The history of the word in English, as varied as it is, also seems to me to point more toward /ˈiːðər/ than /ˈaɪðər/. For example, there's the attested Middle English spelling "eather," and also a handful of other fairly well-established words where "ei" represents /iː/ such as *key, ceiling, seize,* and the set of words ending in *-ceive.*
The OED seems to basically say the same, but notes that in practice both pronunciations have been recommended by the people who deal with such things:

> The pronunciation /ˈaɪðə(r)/ , though not in accordance with the
>   analogies of standard English, is in London somewhat more prevalent in
>   educated speech than /ˈiːðə(r)/ . The orthoepists of 17th cent. seem
>   to give /ˈɛːðər/ , /ˈeːðər/ ; Jones 1701 has /ˈeːðər/ and /ˈaɪðər/ ,
>   Buchanan (1766) has /ˈaɪðə(r)/ without alternative (see Ellis, *Early
>   Eng. Pron.* ix, x.). Walker (1791) says that /ˈiːðə(r)/ and /ˈaɪðə(r)/
>   are both very common, but gives the preference to the former on the
>   ground of analogy and the authority of Garrick. Smart (1849) says that
>   ‘there is little in point of good usage to choose’ between the two
>   pronunciations, though in the body of his dictionary he, like earlier
>   orthoepists, gives /ˈiːðə(r)/ without alternative.

On the other hand, there are a few other English words where "ei" represents /aɪ/. It occurs:

- in *eye* (if we consider "ey" a spelling variant of "ei")
- before "gh" in some words: *[height](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40538/spelling-of-high-vs-height), sleight*
- in words with Greek roots, which I don't believe were ever frequent enough to have had a significant influence on the pronunciation of the common word *either*
- in words that were recently taken from German, as mentioned earlier

I don't know enough about the sound changes leading up to Modern English to be sure, but some other words I found that seem to have undergone similar changes are *fly* n. (Old English *fléoge, flýge*) and *die* v. (Early Middle English *dēȝen, dēghen*).

I suppose it is at least possible that the German digraph influenced English pronunciation along the lines laid out in @GEdgar's comment:

> What I heard (another "hearsay" answer, so I just make a comment) was
>   that Prince Albert, being of German origin, used the pronunciation
>   suggested by German, and then it subsequently became popular among the
>   English.

It seems unlikely to me, but worth mentioning.

It might also be valuable to compare this word's pronunciation with that of *[aye](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aye#English).*

Comment: Somewhere, I picked up an explanation similar to your Prince Albert one, namely that it was King George III who gave the Germanic pronunciation a boost.

Comment: Fun word in the middle there: [orthoepist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orthoepist).

Answer (score 6):

The two pronunciations sound like before and after vowels from the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift). My guess is that we are hearing versions from what were originally two dialects, one which made the shift and one which did not.

Answer (score 5):

> How was it pronounced in old English?

The word *either* is derived from the Old English *ǣgther*, which was a short for contracted form of *ǣg(e)hwæther*, of Germanic origin.

[E-Intro to Old English - 2. Pronunciation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130520093020/http://www.wmich.edu/medieval/resources/IOE/pronunciation.html) reports the Old English pronunciation as it has been reconstructed from linguists.

- *ǣ* as in Modern English *cat*
- *g* as in Modern English *good*
- *th*  as in Modern English *thin*; between voiced vocals as in *then*
- *e* as in Modern English *fate*

Comment: How did they say those words though? How would a speaker do it today?

Comment: I added a link that reports the reconstructed pronunciation of Old English.

Comment: I'd bet 14 florins that the pronunciation depended highly on which village was being sampled.

Comment: Your link is giving me a 404 error, but isn't "g" generally supposed to have had multiple values in Old English? I thought that here it was the palatal variant (sometimes written ġ in modern scholarly works for clarity) that would be pronounced more like the "y" in Modern English "young" (from Old English *ġeong*).

Comment: @sumelic: Yes, this would be the palatal *g* (Modern English *y*), and the *th* (actually *þ*) would be voiced because it’s intervocalic. So it would be IPA [ˈæːjˌðər], which is closer to [ˈaɪˌðɚ] than to [ˈiːˌðɚ].