# Does the pronunciation of "either" change with meaning?

Tags: pronunciation

I was watching a [video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/66aG5P0kQpU?t=18m20s) and the host of the video said:

> We don't say either of these either.

She pronounced the first *either* as EYEther and pronounced the second one as EEther. The first one was used to make choice between the two options while the second was used to mean "too".

Is it usual? Does the pronunciation change meaning in this case? Can I substitute one for the other?

I searched the different pronunciations of either (in this site too) but that didn't help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a rule in British English about how to pronounce "either"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6075/is-there-a-rule-in-british-english-about-how-to-pronounce-either)

Comment: Perhaps confusing idiolect with eye dialect.

Comment: It's quite possible that the host simply didn't want to sound like she was repeating herself.