# Either Pronuciation is OK? or not OK?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, british-english

Either Pronunciation is OK? or not OK? My wife is learning English and she came up with the “either problem”. What to reply? I had always used both pronunciations but in a specific way and seem to remember being taught that way. However, when I went to check this on the net this did not seem to be the case until I saw the comment posted below which was originally posted on this site. This fits with my usage. My Question; Are we correct? is this just an old rule that has become forgot with time? P.S. I am from the UK, Midlands.
Original post: I found that I tend to use "eye-ther" before words beginning with a consonant sound and "ee-ther" before words beginning with a vowel sound. The same applies when I use neither.
E.g. "eye-ther this or that", "eye-ther him or her", "ee-ther a pineapple or a grape", "ee-ther orange or black"

Comment: It sure takes you ages to get to the actual question. Why are you writing backwards like this. You lose your audience.

Comment: It's not clear from the accepted answer in the duplicate, that in BrE the pronunciation is a regional thing. There is another [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/776/why-are-there-two-pronunciations-for-either) too.

Comment: I've never heard of any such rule; some people use one pronunciation and some the other.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make my question clear.  Is the use of  "eye-ther" before words beginning with a consonant sound and "ee-ther" before words beginning with a vowel sound an old rule of grammar?. This question is not referred to in the redirects to duplicate so I think my question is valid.